# Sending data with intent-filter

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

How markets like google play works with `Intent-filter`? 
 I know a little about intent-filter, but I don't know how send data with that?
 How launch an activity with related app data? Do using from `Broadcast Receiver` ? 

 When I browse app **X**, and I want downloaded it, my installed market launched with **X** app info from `complete using action` dialog.
 I don't know how that navigate to related page?

 can anyone explain about that or provide some examples? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

String fileName = sourceFileUri;

```
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null; 
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CameraPhotoCapture.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
        dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" );

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"                             +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
            }
        });

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);




            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); 
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false); 
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename="
                    + fileName + "" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                        File se = new File(full_path_name);

                        String ser = se.getName();

                        String string =full_path_name;
                        String[] parts = string.split("/");
                        String part1 = parts[0]; // 004
                        String part2 = parts[1]; 
                        String part3 = parts[2];
                        String part4 = parts[3];
                        String msg = "http://172.17.2.139/manimca/smartcomplaints/images/"+part4;


                        //    messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(CameraPhotoCapture.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();






                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("complaint_type", $complaint_type));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("complaint_details", $complaint_details));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image_details", $image_details));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude",$latitude));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", $longitude));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("area", $area));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new  BasicNameValuePair("datetime", myDate));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new  BasicNameValuePair("people_name", $people_name));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new  BasicNameValuePair("people_email", $people_email));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new  BasicNameValuePair("people_address", $people_address));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new  BasicNameValuePair("phoneno", $phoneno));


                        try
                        {
                            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://172.17.2.139/manimca/smartcomplaints/complaint_informations.php");
                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            is = entity.getContent();
                            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
                        }

                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }     

                        try
                        {
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                                    (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                            is.close();
                            result = sb.toString();
                            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
                        }     

                        try
                        {
                            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                            code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

                            if(code==1)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });               
            }   
            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            finish();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            dialog.dismiss(); 
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(CameraPhotoCapture.this, "MalformedURLException",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex); 
        } catch (Exception e) {

            dialog.dismiss(); 
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //    messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(CameraPhotoCapture.this, "No Internet Connection ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e); 
        }
        dialog.dismiss();      
        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block
}


public void showMessgeAlert(String Message)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Intent filter Ex:
In this following code using for send data to another activity.

Activity 1:

```
  Intent myintent=new Intent(this,MyListActivity.class);
    myintent.putExtra("latitude", latit);
    myintent.putExtra("longtitude", longet);
    myintent.putExtra("city", cityname);
    myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(myintent);
```

Activity 2:

```
    lat=getIntent().getExtras().getString("latitude").toString();
    longet=getIntent().getExtras().getString("longtitude").toString();
    city=getIntent().getExtras().getString("city").toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I want send data from browser to my app. Let me explain again: consider you navigated to viber homepage and you  want downloaded it, when touched get viber button, `complete action using` dialog appear and when tapped a market such as google play, you launched google play app with related viber page with details. I don't know how do it?

Comment: I understood your thought. Its possible. i was upload image between my app to website. i was use php webservice.

Comment: I was fetch that code. please refer this code for your convenient.

Comment: http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/11/download-file-videoaudiotext-through.html

Answer (score -1):

Add intent filter in your activity tag of manifest, this lets other apps to go to the same activity when corresponding action is requested:

```
 <activity android:name="ShareActivity">
       <!-- filter for sending text or images; accepts SEND action and text or image data -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And then in your activity, handle the intent:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the intent that started this activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();

    // Figure out what to do based on the intent type
    if (intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1) {
        // Handle intents with image data ...
    } else if (intent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
        // Handle intents with text ...
    }
}
```

You can also return results to the caller activity(i.e. when some other app called your activity with startActivityForResult):

```
Intent result = new Intent("com.example.RESULT_ACTION", Uri.parse("content://result_uri");
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I got it null. How detect It is from browser? I don't know you code means. Can you provide more details?

Comment: was it the same action that you caught from intent-filter? Here are the list of actions that you can catch from other apps:  sdk/platforms/android-x/data/broadcast_actions.txt

Comment: "How detect It is from browser?" You can't if the browser calls your app with startActivity(). However, you can get it if the browser calls your app with startActivityForResult() using getCallingActivity(). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity()

Comment: If you just want package name, you have getCallingPackage ()